# How to convert a text in a file into bytes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text in a file in my directory. I want to convert it into bytes. How can I do it with Python3?

Comment: Just open it as a binary file, in the call to `open` use the options string `'rb'`.

Comment: Alrighty !! @Paul..and if I want to copy its content to other file??

Comment: don't bother opening it, in that case just copy it using `shutil` or another applicable module.

Comment: Thanks @Paul..can I decode it into a string again after opening it in 'rb'

Comment: Sure see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string).

Comment: @Paul..could you write the code here for me to understand.. I'm a Python amateur.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file is named `filename.ext` and you are running in the parent directory of `dir`, then you could try the following code:

```
with open('dir/filename.ext', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()

    # Do something with contents
```

If all you want is to copy the file, then you could do this:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('dir/filename.txt', 'dir/copiedfile.txt')
```

This will create a `copiedfile.txt` in the `dir` directory.